# &lt; and all those characters in my xml

Tags: xml, spring, xml-parsing

I am sending a xml string to the server from form post. On server all `<`, `>`, `"` are replaced into corresponding `&lt;` `&gt;` characters. Before parsing that string, how do I get my original string. Due to this my parsing is failing.

Comment: How are you reading the data on the server? It doesn't seem logical that the form data would be HTML encoded.

Comment: I am creating a XML, putting it in a hidden field before submitting to the server.

Comment: Are you HTML encoding it when you put it in the hidden field?

Comment: I have just created an xml plaintext string as follows -

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>.......`

and put it in hidden field. Not doing anything else.

Comment: What you describe doesn't normally happen, there is no reason for form data to ever get HTML encoded. If you can show the code for putting the value in the field, and the code for getting the value on the server side, it might be possible to spot the problem.